# C# pattern matching with manipulated value of property

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

Let's say I have a class

```cs
public class Foo
{
  public int Bar { get; set; }
  
  public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

And I initialize this in a variable.

```cs
var foo = new Foo
{
  Bar = 123,
  Baz = "123"
};
```

Is it possible to pattern match this with the value manipulated?

Because I can do:

```cs
if (test is { Bar: >= 100 })
{
  // do
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

```cs
if (test is { Bar: >= 100, Baz: value.Length > 5 })
{
  // do
}
```

Above syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested property pattern `{Length: > 5}` should do the trick:

```
if (foo is { Bar: >= 100, Baz: {Length: > 5}})
{
    // do
}
```

Comment: , means AND or OR?

Comment: @viveknuna `AND`

Comment: @viveknuna [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjTQG4CGATogGYD27iAvIgHYBTAO6IAYp2q1aWGFLm4AQsx6IIYeABpJ82koBeKgERr4h7fIC+AbnNyAlq0SkOXOwGdMiJUwBciAHy8EAAMwYgaXgx6fhgAMgJ8AOYALgAWfv6IAKwWFuS2UjI6cgD0JYgAJuwFOiAQAJykhlWG5DayxYgW2t0dODUIyGBiEn3SNTSDdnzJkSwYiIkCyVaIbsurvf1j8oN1YfqeSytrG101vRZAA)